# Looking for a value in a column of many tables

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a method returning Boolean in my repository. Its job is to look for the value that is passed in and see if ANY of the tables in their personnel_key column have that value.
So for example:

```
public bool IsPersonnelKeyDuplicate(string per_k)
{
   var result = (from f in this.Context.Personnel where f.personnel_key  == per_k select f).Any();
   return result;
}
```

So that is how I am looking in one of those tables. But I have like 20 more tables to add to this method. What is a good way of doing this?  Do you suggest I write a big "OR" of all these ".Any()" statements?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of searching every table you should use foreign keys, databases are very good at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LINQ to Entities like you posted is all you can use: Then yes. That is the way to go.
But if will be extremely inefficient as you will be querying database for N times.
See if you can use normal `ADO` and `SQL` commands, then you will only query the database one time and not N times.